# How to add attributes to custom HTML key [img]/path/to/image.jpg[/img]?

Tags: javascript, image, replace, src

I have an online text editor, very well made however it does not currently support images.

I have this at the moment and don't feel it to be a very good way of doing it.

```
var = txt = "some text here oh and here's my image! [img]linktoimage.jpg[/img]";
var = txt.replace(/[img]/g, '<img src="');
var = txt.replace(/[/img]/g, '" alt="" />');
return txt;
```

And how would I go about adding attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a replacement function, to replace the substring as a whole and to build the replacement string more easily:

```
txt = txt.replace(/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/g, function(match, src) {
    return '<img src="' + src + '" alt="" />';
});
```

For more information, have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Comment: I smell a syntax error. You forgot to escape the `/` in `[/img]`. You also need to escape `[` and `]` (even though the latter is not really necessary)

Comment: Interesting.. it wasn't a syntax error at all (but still incorrect of course). Apparently even `/` doesn't need to be escaped inside a character class. I'd have expected the JS parser to be more separated from the regex parser.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Anyways, I had to escape the `[` at least so that it is not a character class.